# "sqlite3.h" missing when pushing Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, sqlite, push

I'm following [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:deploying_the_demo_app), but it fails when I try to push to Heroku.  It seems "sqlite3.h" is missing.  I'm new to development so I'm not sure what information will help people diagnose the problem, so here's everything :).  I'm running on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.  Here are the versions of everything I'm working with:

```
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.3
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ sqlite3 -version
3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50 00bb9c9ce4f465e6ac321ced2a9d0062dc364669
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ heroku -v
2.25.0
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ port -v
MacPorts 2.0.4
Entering interactive mode... ("help" for help, "quit" to quit)
[RailsApps/demo_app] > quit 
Goodbye
```

When I try to push to Heroku:

```
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ heroku create --stack cedar
Creating floating-stream-8009... done, stack is cedar
http://floating-stream-8009.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:floating-stream-8009.git
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ git push heroku master
```

Here's what I get:

```
Counting objects: 119, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (104/104), done.
Writing objects: 100% (119/119), 33.74 KiB, done.
Total 119 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Installing rake (0.9.2.2)
       .
       .
       .
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       .
       .
       .
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2l2dn7bx7lu34/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2l2dn7bx7lu34/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:blazing-mountain-3659.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blazing-mountain-3659.git'
```

When I do:

```
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ sudo port install sqlite3 +universal
```

I get:

```
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for sqlite3
--->  Cleaning sqlite3
```

Next I tried:

```
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'
```

And get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-1.3.6...
```

Then:

```
Amits-MacBook-Air-2:demo_app amitgupta$ bundle install
```

gives:

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
.
.
.
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
Using uglifier (1.2.4) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Then I try pushing to Heroku again, but get the same problem.  Perhaps it has something to do with the discrepancy between the first command "Creating floating-stream-8009" and the second command "failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blazing-mountain-3659.git'"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Heroku uses postgresql so you want to remove sqlite3 or move it into a development group in your Gemfile.

Check you Gemfile.lock for any other gems that may have dependencies on sqlite3, as this can also cause problems.

Comment: Once you remove sqlite3 from the gemfile, and save the gem file, and check gemfile.lock and confirm there are no other references to it - THEN - what are the next steps? I'm still pushing to Heroku and getting that same error - but I feel like it shouldn't be looking for sqlite3 now.

Comment: @stopshinal dont forget to commit the changes in the gem file again locally before pushing it again into heroku

Comment: @DanS, is there any formal document that indicates sqlite3 is not supported any more?

Answer (score 53):

```
gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

1. edit `Gemfile` as above
2. remove `Gemfile.lock`
3. run `bundle install --without production`
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -am "bundle updating sqlite3"`
6. `git push heroku master`

Comment: Thanx! This was the solution for me.

Comment: Thank you. It fixed my problem though it was not chosen by the OP.

Comment: kind explanation for newbies like me ;-)

Comment: Nice. An explanation though of what is happening would be great!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I wasn't even using sqlite3 for anything but after removing it from the gem file I still got that error

what solved it for me was a commit command

```
git commit -am
```

that I found on [this tutorial](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

What happened to me was, I was following along the Heroku tutorial and when I used `git push heroku master` it was pushing from my latest Git commit (obviously!)

What I forgot was that in the eyes of Git, I was still using sqlite in the gemfile! Silly me!

So I used `git add .` followed by a `git commit -m "Changed to Postgres."` so Git knew about these changes. Pushing after that worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as these answers suggest, *most* of the time you will want to avoid using SQLite in production [due to the constraints of the Heroku platform](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#disk-backed-storage). **However**, you may have a [perfectly acceptable use case](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23281994) (ex. read-only config) for using SQLite anyway. My recommendation is to:

1. Add the [`heroku-buildpack-apt`](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) buildpack
2. Add to your `Aptfile`:

   ```
   libsqlite3-dev
   libsqlite3-0
   ```