# Troubles with Heroku cloud hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a problem with deploying my Ruby on Rails project into heroku cloud hosting - [heroku cloud hosting](http://www.heroku.com)

When I am pushing my code through Git bush I have a problem with installing sqlite3... but how to go through this error I don't know... maybe someone can help me with this problem?

Error screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: What's your exact error message?

Comment: @Blender here is error screenshoot - [screenshoot](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/5918/herokuerror.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku uses postgresql. Move `sqlite3` gem into a development group.

Step-by-step instructions provided by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11356442/1153362

Comment: thanx man, it's realy helps=)

Answer (score 1):

on Heroku sqlite don't use, transfer your data from sqlite to postgresql